# Adding many images to HBox causes display problems in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

In Flex, I'm using an HBox to hold thumbnails. When more thumbnails are added than can be shown, the HBox becomes scrollable.

When I add more than, say, 80 images, when I scroll back to the first image, the images begin "tearing", until I hover my mouse over them.

This is how it looks when few images are added:

[image: Expected]

When many images are added:

[image: Buggy]

Should I be using something other than an HBox to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HBox doesn't use virtual renders so I'd actually recommend a List based control like [HorizontalList](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/HorizontalList.html).  You may also want to use Ely Greenfield's [SuperImage](http://www.quietlyscheming.com/blog/2007/01/29/new-flex-componentsample-superimage/) to avoid flicker when scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the list controls!

Answer (score 1):

Use a TileList.
It can use ItemRenderers which uses fewer resources.